# setting up Yii1.13 on shared server error

Tags: php, yii

i want to upload a web site the shared server.

**structure**

- public_html

  - Yii(folder)
  - index.php (inside root folder)

I'm just getting this message "Server ERROR".please can someone tell me where is the problem or what should i change in my code to make it work.here is my index code:

```
<?php

// yii directory paths<br/>
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/yii/yii.php';

$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';

// remove the following lines when in production mode<br/>

defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);

// specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message<br/>
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);
require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();

?>
```

Comment: First things I would check is if PHP is enabled and working correctly (create a phpinfo() page) and double check all your paths. Also your web host may have some server logs that will hopefully have more detail about the error

Comment: i use the yii requirements check and it told that server configuration is ok for yii. i install a welcome yii application and it loaded very well ((( but my web application on the same server is showing nothing only SERVER ERROR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could install a welcome yii application successfully then it is the problem of the index.php file in your app itself. One easy method is to copy the index.php file generated by your demo app and copy paste it in your original app. Make sure to keep the app in the same place where you kept your demo app.
Also, make sure that your vendor directories are there if you have used composer as well. Then check if the permissions are given correctly to the folders. Specifically the runtime and the assets folder. If in doubt you can simply chmod 777 on them.
If it is still giving error then there must be a problem with something you are using within your app which is probably missing something.
P.s please do express the error message properly so that we can get a better idea of the problem that you are facing.

Comment: THANK !!! i make all you said and check the log file an ROWAN said also. Server Logs is great!it show me that an unexpected "[" exist in my code. when i try to comment that line of code, the web page is showing but that line is the main controller of every page because all the content depends on it. all page working navigation but with the main content div empty !!! i think that this code... $contents = [$page_name,$content]; return $contents; is not a mistake in PHP . but change this 2 lines of code with ... $contents[]=$page_name; $contents[]=$content;return $contents; and everything is OK!